# HP Officejet Pro X 451dw doesn't work with Focal Fossa, though it did with Bionic Beaver

Tags: printing, hp

Half a year ago I was fed up with windows and decided to install Xubuntu. I first tried a live system of Focal Fossa, but my printer, an HP Officejet Pro X451dw wouldn't work.
I found out, that it does with Bionic Beaver, installed it and worked happily with it since.
Yesterday I decided to upgrade to Focal Fossa, because the support for Bionic Beaver will run out soon. But unfortunately, the problem reoccurred.
The printing utility detects the printer, but I can't print. I get a notification, that the printer is not connected, which is definitely wrong. I have disconnected the USB cable and reconnected it to varying USB slots, but that didn't change anything.
I removed the printer from the printing utility and reinstalled it, without success.
I ran troubelshooting and got the following protocol:

```
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=0, altset=0, index=1
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=0 ret=0
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 515: invalid claim_interface 7/1/2: Device or resource busy
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=0, altset=1, index=3
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=0 ret=0
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 515: invalid claim_interface 7/1/4: Device or resource busy
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=2, altset=0, index=9
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=2 ret=0
I [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] io/hpmud/musb.c 515: invalid claim_interface ff/4/1: Device or resource busy
E [03/Mär/2021:08:18:41] prnt/backend/hp.c 825: INFO: open device failed stat=21: hp:/usb/HP_Officejet_Pro_X451dw_Printer?serial=CN4CDJX05B; will retry in 30 seconds...
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=0, altset=0, index=1
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=0 ret=0
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 515: invalid claim_interface 7/1/2: Device or resource busy
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=0, altset=1, index=3
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=0 ret=0
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 515: invalid claim_interface 7/1/4: Device or resource busy
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 427: Found interface conf=0, iface=2, altset=0, index=9
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 389: Active kernel driver on interface=2 ret=0
I [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] io/hpmud/musb.c 515: invalid claim_interface ff/4/1: Device or resource busy
E [03/Mär/2021:08:19:50] prnt/backend/hp.c 825: INFO: open device failed stat=21: hp:/usb/HP_Officejet_Pro_X451dw_Printer?serial=CN4CDJX05B; will retry in 30 seconds...
```

Does anybody know a solution to my problem?
May I use Focal Fossa with an older version of the printing utility?
How dangerous would it be to reinstall Bionic Beaver and continue using it, after the support runs out?

Comment: I would discourage you from mixing and matching across Ubuntu versions.  It's probably worth your time to solve the problem with Focal Fossa instead.  By printing utility, I presume you meant `cups`?  Have you installed [hplip](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing), which is also an Ubuntu package called `hplip`?  (Maybe the GUI `hplip-gui` package would also help?)

Comment: I have been told at freenodes webchat, that I need to remove ippusbxd to resolve a conflict  and have run "sudo apt purge ippusbxd" and "sudo rmmod ippusbxd" and rebooted the computer, but it had no effect.
I still can't print and still get the notification "printer possibly not connected"

Comment: When I install the printer, the printing utility says: "connection: HP Linux Imaging and Printing (HPLIP)"
Doesn't that mean hplip is installed? 
How can I get hplip-gui?

Comment: The OfficeJet Pro X451dw should work OOTB on Focal. See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues

Comment: Try `sudo apt update; sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui`.  You've also installed `cups`?

Comment: I have run sudo apt update and sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui and uploaded the output of my terminal at:
https://imgur.com/a/2MVUSMD
Then I have removed and reinstalled the printer. It had no effect so far, but I guess I need to reboot first. That's what I'm going to do next.

Comment: I have rebooted, removed and reinstalled the printer, but I was not able to print a testpage. Now I get the following notification:
HPLIP device status HP-HP_Officejet-Pro-X451dw-Printer Device busy: TestPage

Comment: But also the known notification: printer possibly not connected.

Comment: I have run ps -aux and found the process
root  814......../usr/sbin/cupsd -l
Doesn't that mean, that cups is running?
If you want, you can find the whole output of ps -aux on
https://imgur.com/a/2MVUSMD

Comment: As I will urgently need my computer after easter, I am considering installing another Linux distribution. But I fear, probably the problem is due to ubuntu itself and will occur on all distributions, that use the newest Ubuntu?
I could try Debian or Linux Mint for example. My last hope would be, to install Suse and hope for their professional assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I have finally discarded Xubuntu and installed Linuxmint. I am very happy with the decision. Printing worked at once, the documentation and instructions are much more detailed, a higher emphasis on security and the best of all:
The LTS - Version I have installed will be supported until April 2025! A stable system for 4 years, thank goodness!